# Calculate the area of a circle by integrating in a specific way by dividing the upper semi-circle into rectangles and then adding their areas.

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, area

I was trying to figure out the area of a circle through integration. I derived the formula by figuring out the area of a quadrant and then multiplying it by 4 but then I decided to do it slightly differently and that's where I'm stuck. Imagine a semi-circle. Now divide it into many rectangles with decreasing side lengths as we progress towards the pole, but equal widths. Let the width be dx. Any of the many rectangles would have both the lengths nearly equal. Now if areas of all such rectangles are calculated and added then we should get the area of semi-circle and its 2 times will be the area of the circle.
Length of any rectangle can be calculated by 2(rcosx)(x=central angle). In not able to set up the an equation. [image: I have showed what I mean in the image.]

Comment: So what?.........

Comment: Since the width is $dx$, obviously the variable of integration has to be $x$ (the distance from the horizontal axis). You need to write $\cos\theta$ in terms of $x$ (and $r$). Or equivalent, write $r\cos\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $r$, using Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: I'm not able to set up the equation. I need help with that.

Comment: Also if you can show the full step by step process, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @John1085 Do you just mean $\pi r^2=4\int_{0}^r \sqrt {r^2-y^2}dy$?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but... How do you know if Golden_Ratio is a man? :)

Comment: @CiaPan I'm sorry. My bad. I didn't mean to assume the gender.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thank you. I didn't think of setting it up that way.

Answer (score 1):

it makes most sense to call the vertical heights $dy$ and calculate area in terms of $\int x dy$
$$ x = r \cos(\theta) $$
$$ y = r \sin(\theta) \implies dy=r \cos(\theta) d \theta  $$
$$A = 4 \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} r^2 \cos^2(\theta ) d \theta  $$

We know that $\cos^2(\theta)$ has an average value of $\frac 12$ , So ...

$$  A = 2r^2   \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} d \theta  = \pi r^2 $$

Comment: Thank you so much.